# Downcast from 'String?' to 'String' only unwraps optionals

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to read a `.mid` file from the `DocumentDirectory`. I tried this:

```
var path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first as! String
var midiFileURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path)
```

The problem is:

> Downcast from 'String?' to 'String' only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!'?

Once I read the file from the `DocumentsDirectory` I want to be able to play it back with this:

```
guard let bankURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("gs_instruments", withExtension: "dls") else {
    fatalError("\"gs_instruments.dls\" file not found.")
}

do {
    try self.midiPlayer = AVMIDIPlayer(contentsOfURL: midiFileURL, soundBankURL: bankURL)
    print("created midi player with sound bank url \(bankURL)")
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Error \(error.localizedDescription)")
}

self.midiPlayer.prepareToPlay()

self.midiPlayer.play({
    print("midi done")
})
```

*How do I fix the error? Many thanks.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first` is returning you an `Optional<String>` (a.k.a. `String?`). You're trying to cast this to `String`. The warning is telling you that you're doing this in a cumbersome way. You can just force unwrap it with `!`:

```
var path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first!
```

Of course, because you're force unwrapping, you risk your application crashing in case the value returned is `nil` (in the case that there is no `first`... when the collection is empty).

I highly advise you read about Optionals in the [Swift Language Guide - The Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html).

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Please take the time to read the language guide. It does a fantastic job of explaining things, especially features as core to the language as Optionals.

Comment: I think if you use [0] instead of .first you don't get an optional.

Comment: @PhoneyDeveloper Even though it's longer, I kinda prefer `.first!`. It makes the danger a bit more explicit, and it's also more consistent with how i would use `.last!` as opposed to `arr[arr.count-1]`